# Using Window Functions With Comparison Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query within a cte.

```
SELECT   [item_id]
         FROM [AWS_Stage]
         WHERE [yr] IN('2020')
         GROUP BY [item_id]
         HAVING SUM(ISNULL([frcst_qty], 0)) >= 0
```

In the past I just needed all item_id's in 2020 greater than 0.

I now need to have all item id's greater than 0 by customer groupings. A line of code like the following makes sense:

```
SUM([frcst_qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY [item_id], [keycust4])  >= 0
```

I can't use a window function in a HAVING clause, and I can't have a comparison operator in the SELECT statement.

Any advice on how to make this work?

Comment: please provide some sample data and your desired output in table format

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using a subquery like below? This calculated the sum using window function and then using filter on the result. I removed year condition.

```
SELECT
        [item_id]
FROM
        (
                SELECT
                        [item_id],
                        SUM([frcst_qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY  [item_id], [keycust4] ORDER BY [item_id], [keycust4]) sum_qty
                FROM
                        [AWS_Stage] ) subq
WHERE
        sum_qty >=0
GROUP BY
        [item_id]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select [keycust4], [item_id]
from [aws_stage]
where [yr] = '2020'
group by [keycust4], [item_id]
having SUM(ISNULL([frcst_qty], 0)) >= 0
```

try this. not sure though if i understood your question correctly